# Run protractor tests in parallel with JUnitXmlReporter

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Im running the protractor specs in parallel and generating an xml report. the problem is the report is being overridden instead of consolidating all the specs results.

protractor.config.js is as follows:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 5
```

},

```
onPrepare: function () {
var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: 'TestReports',
    filePrefix: 'xmloutput',
    consolidate: true
}));
},
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Protractor-cookbook? There's an example of a [jasmine junit reporter](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/tree/master/jasmine-junit-reports). In the example the tests are conslidated to a single xml file.

I would also remove the sharding to make sure that sharded tests are not causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks.. but I want to run the specs in sharding mode.. is there any way to consolidate reports into one report with shardTestFiles set to true?

Comment: I have not tried that yet. Let me know how it goes.